# Render component not update after setstate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state, render

I have a component like this:

```
... imports

class ChooseGenres extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.setState({
            event: { ... , genres: [] },
            genres: [{...}, {...}, {...}]
        });
    }

    eventHasGenre(item, genre_id) {
        return item.genres.indexOf(genre_id) > -1 ? true : false;
    }

    onGenreChange(genre_id) {
        let event = this.state.event;

        if (this.eventHasGenre(event, genre_id)) {
            event.genres.splice(indexOf, 1)
        } else {
            event.genres.push(genre_id);
        }

        this.setState({
            event: event
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Content>
                    <List dataArray={this.state.genres}
                        renderRow={(item) =>
                            <ListItem onPress={this.onGenreChange.bind(this, item.id)}>
                                <Body>
                                    <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                                </Body>
                                {this.eventHasGenre(this.state.event, item.id) &&
                                    <Right>
                                        <Icon active name="arrow-forward" />
                                    </Right>
                                }
                            </ListItem>
                        }>
                    </List>
                </Content>
            </Container>
}

ChooseGenres.propTypes = {
    isLoggedIn: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        isLoggedIn: state.isLoggedIn
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    startup: () => dispatch(StartupActions.startup())
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ChooseGenres);
```

When I click on ListItem I add the genre to the event.genres array, and I want the Icon to be shown.
But even if the event object in the state is updated correctly (I log it in the console), the Icon is still not shown.

The strange behaviour I noticed is if I back in the navigation and I came back to this Component, the Icons are shown correctly.

Comment: Does your render's return need a closing parenthesis?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you don't need to do `setState` in the constructor since it is useless as the *component has not been rendered*

Second, you're trying to mutate the state in `onGenreChange` function.
You dont need extra redundant **genres array** inside **events object**, just another tag would work

```
state = {
  genres: [{id: 1, name: 1}, {id: 2, name: 2}, {id: 3, name: 3}]
}



onGenreChange = (id) => {
    const genres = this.state.genres.map(genre => {
      if (genre.id === id) {
        return {...genre, active: !genre.active}
      }
      return genre
    })
    this.setState({
      genres
    });
  }

<List dataArray={this.state.genres}
      renderRow={(item) =>
        <ListItem onPress={() => this.onGenreChange(item.id)}>
          <Body>
            <Text>{item.name}</Text>
           </Body>
           {item.active &&
             <Right>
               <Icon active name="arrow-forward" size={20} color={'red'}/>
              </Right>
           }
         </ListItem>
        }>
</List>
```

Comment: As I commented to @Sterling Beason post, it is not what I needed but you too let me understand what was I doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: If you directly mutate the state object, then it won't re render the part of the dom tree affected by that state

Answer (score 1):

You are rendering:

```
this.state.genres
```

but setting state of:

```
this.state.event.genres
```

Try updating your render function to this:

```
render() {
    return (
        <Container>
            <Content>
                <List dataArray={this.state.event.genres}
                    renderRow={(item) =>
                        <ListItem onPress={this.onGenreChange.bind(this, item.id)}>
                            <Body>
                                <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                            </Body>
                            {this.eventHasGenre(this.state.event, item.id) &&
                                <Right>
                                    <Icon active name="arrow-forward" />
                                </Right>
                            }
                        </ListItem>
                    }>
                </List>
            </Content>
        </Container>
}
```

Comment: You right. Even if it is not what I needed, I got the point and you let me understand. I thought that changing the state would have caused all component to be rerendered.